# Reflection not working for Spring autowired parameters

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, dao

I'm trying to generate an integration test without using @DataJpaTest in order to understand better the concepts.
I've noticed that with Reflection I'm not able to get or set The Dao within my Service layer under test. So when it comes to access the Dao got with Reflection API it returns a NullPointerException. I've tested both Java Reflection API and ReflectionTestUtils of Spring Framework. Here is the snippet of code

```
UserService userService;

@Before
public void setUp(){
   userService = new UserServiceImpl();
   UserDao userDao = (UserDao) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(userService, "userDao");
   userDao.deleteAll(); //HERE RETURNS A NULLPOINTER
   ...
}
```

Consider that in UserServiceImpl.java I inject UserDao (Interface which extends JpaRepository using @Autowired annotation of Spring framework.

How can I access the Dao (implemented by Spring framework) from my Service? Thanks!

Comment: can you put full stack trace. is userDao null or it is throwing NullPointer in some other internal call?

Comment: userDao attribute inside RestController is null, so when I try to get it with Reflection I get a null object. I don't know how to access an @Autowired UserDao interface from my Integration tests.

Comment: You are manually creating the `UserServiceImpl`. You should autowire it and let spring create the object. Then it will populate all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One handy trick is to make sure your test Spring configuration is working correctly by verifying your autowired dependencies are actually getting autowired. For example:

```
@Autowired
UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
UserServiceImpl userService;

@Test
public void verifySpringContext() {
    assertNotNull(userDao);
    assertNotNull(userService.getUserDao());
}
```

I suspect that there's an issue with the Spring configuration in your test, preventing userDao from being autowired.

Comment: Infact I forgot to insert @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and also I used the constructor of UserServiceImpl instead of letting Spring inject it. It's the right answer because it brought me to the solution! Thanks!